# C# / XAML: datagrid - binding an item with 'SelectedItem'

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, binding, selecteditem

I am struggling to get a binding correct.

In the codebehind I receive a collection of my type `DataContainer`called **_dataCollection** which is supposed to be tied with a custom DataGrid in XAML and a single `DataContainer`**_currentItem** which I need to find again in the **_dataCollection** and then set as selected item in my DataGrid. And once the selection is changed by user the **_currentItem** should change to.

Not really anything hard, but for some reason I can't figure an easy way out.

Comment: Well, you have ItemsSource and Selecteditem to databind to. Also pay attention to the SelectionMode.

Comment: You need to set the data context also. Put your important parts of your code so people can learn.